# Too many whitespaces when outputting blade variables?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

A bit of background: I'm trying to create user-editable pages in a blog-style web application. The application consists of multiple pages worth of content included into one page; dynamically generated from the back-end and laid out one under the other.
Note: I am a Laravel newbie.

The content of the pages is kept in the DB; one DB record = page title + content. I retrieve all records and send them to the template:

```
class ContentController extends Controller {
    var $current_content;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->current_content = Content::all();
    }

    public function serveContent() {
        return View::make('home')->with('pages', $this->current_content);
    }
}
```

Over in the template I iterate through the object with the freshly retrieved data and display the contents for each page:

```
@foreach($pages as $page)
    <section class="page">
        <div class="editable-page" id="{{ $page->page }}">
            {{ $page->content }}
        </div>
        <div hidden class="editable-page-edit-mode" id="{{ $page->page }}">
            <textarea class="page-edit">
                {{ $page->content }}
            </textarea>
        </div>
        <input hidden type="button" class="edit-btn" value="Edit {{ $page->page }} section"/>
    </section>
@endforeach
```

(The textarea is for the edit mode, it contains the same content as above; except this time it will be sent back to the DB).

The problem is that when outputting the variable contents with `{{ $page->content }}`, an absurd amount of whitespaces seem to be introduced.

Here's how the section looks in the browser: http://prntscr.com/bzeu4l
And here's what happens behind the scenes: http://prntscr.com/bzets2

Normally it would be completely and utterly irrelevant to me since the content is displayed properly. But when I unhide the textarea, it's clear that it receives the exact same data, with whitespaces: http://prntscr.com/bzeum8

This is a big problem because I don't want the DB values to be overwritten with spaces.

I **could** work around this by using regex and stripping what has more than 2 spaces when I save the data. But this feels like a workaround, not a solution.

Does anyone know an elegant solution to this? Since I'm a Laravel newbie, it's very possible that I'm missing something obvious about displaying variable values in Blade.
Thanks in advance.

PS: If anybody has any suggestions about my approach / if my approach with the textarea is flawed, I warmly welcome criticism.
Also, I am terribly sorry for the vague layout of the page, it's still in a very incipient stage. In case it's not evident, 'testhomecontent' and 'testservices' are practically $page[0]->content and $page[1]->content.

Comment: make sure there are no line breaks between the <textarea> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In blade when all spaces between the contents are preserved. So, to get rid of spaces change your following code

```
<div hidden class="editable-page-edit-mode" id="{{ $page->page }}">
            <textarea class="page-edit">
                {{ $page->content }}
            </textarea>
        </div>
```

To this:

```
<textarea class="page-edit">{{ $page->content }}</textarea>
```

Comment: I was certain I missed something entirely obvious, good thing I asked. Thank you for your response, fixed. It makes perfect sense too.

Comment: glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<textarea class="page-edit">
    {{ $page->content }}
</textarea>
```

To

```
<textarea class="page-edit">{{ $page->content }}</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, you are right and the problem is fixed. Unfortunately, I accepted the other answer since it was written before you and has extra details. I hope this doesn't bother you. Thanks again for replying.

Comment: That's very generous of you that you up voted my answer.

Comment: The least I could do, friend :). Take care.